# Eigenvalues of a block matrix.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help in the following question:

Suppose I have a complex matrix $A$ with svd decomposition.

Consider the block matrix $B$ such that
$$B=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & A^* \\
 A & 0\\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \quad
 $$
Where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Explain why B has real eigenvalues and at least one of the eigenvalues is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix has real eigenvalues since it's hermitian. But the second claim is in general false. Counterexample: Zero is not an eigenvalue of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. The claim is true if $A$ is not square, though.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you. May I ask why the claim will be true if A is not square? Is it due to the matrix not invertible? How do you manage to see it? Kindly advise.

Comment: I think I know why. The nullspace of B contains more than just the zero vector if A is not square. Hence B is singular, hence will have at least one eigenvalue of 0.

Comment: Yes. Either $A$ or $A^*$ has non-trivial null space then.